What is Iran's long-term objective in the Middle East?
Is it Iran's objective to

change the total Western-led order in the Middle East so that Iran doesn't have to live under sanctions?

create a sovereign Palestinian state?

root out Israel?

take control of Mecca and Medina?

all of the above?


I mean, what is their ultimate goal?

Top prio is to convert the shia crescent moon to a well-working and strong alliance, under their leadership.

Iran's ultimate goal since the foundation of the Islamic Republic has always been the exportation of revolution. Even the main cause of the Iran-Iraq war was Khomeini's ambition to incite Iraqi Shiites against Saddam. In fact, the Islamic Republic wants to occupy Jerusalem (which it calls the liberation of Jerusalem). Khomeini frequently said during the war against Iraq:

The path to Jerusalem passes through Karbala.

Karbala is a city in Iraq that is sacred to Shiites, and Khomeini meant that they should occupy this city to pave the way for the occupation of Jerusalem.
Put simply, Iran under the Islamic Republic seeks to establish an Islamic caliphate in which Iran's leader is the leader of all Muslims. To achieve this, they want to control all regions from Iran to the Mediterranean Sea. This is why, in Persian media, the Islamic Republic's leader is referred to as the leader of all Muslims. Finally, the Islamic Republic's claims about occupying Jerusalem and wiping Israel off the map can be verified by:

Iranian officials' statements regarding the elimination of Israel. For example, Abbas Nilforoushan, an IRGC commander, said in an interview:


I was born into a revolutionary family, so since I was 6 years old, I
wished to wipe Israel off the map and die for this cause.

He died in the Beirut bombardment last week alongside Hassan Nasrallah.

Khamenei's propaganda poster on Twitter, in which we see pro-Islamic Republic figures like Qassem Soleimani in Jerusalem, using the expression the final solution.



Shiites muslims consider Karbala as a holy site because of the incident that took there in history. So it's most likely that it was said to create inspiration from Karbala incident among the people( not invade that place ) .

Fair enough, but how does Iran see the Shia-Sunni schism as compatible with them being the big Islamic boss?

@ItalianPhilosopher   Probably through jihad. Shia Muslims are followers of Imam Ali, known for his military campaigns. Anyway, this is very simplistic, but the mullahs believe it is possible. They have already recruited some Sunni Muslims, such as those from Hamas and PIJ, and they think they can extend their influence. This is no more illogical than what they call the liberation of Jerusalem.

@ItalianPhilosopher, the Shia-Sunni schism was over exactly that point: was Muhammad's true successor Ali ibn Abi Talib (Shia) or Abu Bakr (Sunni)?

To stick with the obvious they are calling/hoping a lot for the destruction of Israel. This is from their previous president (deceased last spring), but there's no shortage of people like that in Iran's ruling circles:

I hope that God will liberate Palestine as soon as possible, and we witness the final moments of Israel's existence and celebrate its end.

And one can be rather sure that part of "Marg Bar Amrika" is at least getting rid of US bases in the region, which are subject to regular attacks by Iran-linked groups.
As for the Saudi issue, some in Israel surely allege that's what Iran plans as well, but Iran itself is perhaps less overt about it. Take this statement for instance, from the Supreme Leader:

The Leader of the Revolution asserted that the land of Holy Mecca belongs to all Muslims and added: “The land of Mecca belongs to all Muslims. No one should think they can do whatever they want on this land. All Muslims have the same right with regard to Mecca and Medina.”

Make of this "Mecca communism" (if I am to coin a term) what you will. But it looks to me to be attempting to undermine at least to some degree the Saudi state (and the royal family in particular) claim of guardianship of those places.

There's a religious component that cannot be ignored here. Iran (predominantly Shiite Muslim) has a belief in something called The 12th Imam

They believe that a series of Imams was appointed to carry on the Prophet Muhammad's message and that these Imam rank above all other prophets except for Muhammad himself. The 12th, Muhammad al-Mahdi, is believed by these Shiites to have been born in present-day Iraq in 869 and never to have died, only gone into hiding. Twelvers—not other Shiites or Sunni Muslims—believe that al-Mahdi will return as a messiah with Jesus to bring peace to the world and establish Islam as the ruling faith across the globe.
The apocalyptic catch? The Mahdi is expected to appear when the world is wracked by utter chaos and war. Many Sunnis also believe that the Mahdi will come in such a judgment day scenario, but believe that he has not been born yet.

This isn't some fringe belief either. The leaders of Iran tend to believe in this.

Ayatollah Ruhollah Khomeini, the father of the Islamic Revolution in Iran, was a Twelver. So is the current Supreme Leader, Ayatollah Ali Khamenei, and [now former] President Mahmoud Ahmadinejad.

And

The Twelver beliefs have raised concern in conjunction with Iran's steeped interest in furiously pressing forward with its nuclear program, combined with threats against Israel and the West. Critics of the Islamic Republic allege that Ahmadinejad and the Supreme Leader would even go so far as to hasten a nuclear showdown and cataclysmic strike—perhaps an attack on Israel and inevitable retaliation—to hasten the arrival of the 12th Imam. Ahmadinejad has even called for the reappearance of the 12th Imam from the podium of the United Nations General Assembly. During his speeches within Iran, Ahmadinejad has said that the main mission of the Islamic Revolution is to pave the way for the reappearance of the 12th Imam.

It's hard to pin down any one action on this, but it's easier to understand some of Iran's more self-destructive decisions in light of this. Iran wants to dominate the region politically, but if they start a war in the process they believe it could bring about the return of their savior who will end all suffering.

So, a bit like the claims that US Evangelicals are very, very, pro-Israel because that will bring Armageddon and the Second Coming?  It would be nice to actually quote some of their statements to that effect though, including if possible their willingness to go to war for specifically that reason.

@ItalianPhilosopher If you can find any US political leaders who actually espouse that view (like the president of the country) sure. My link contains several quotes from Ahmadinejad, who claims it is a view focused on peace (which is clearly why Iran backs terrorist organizations).

Your link doesn't quote A. saying that they would go to war.  Not saying that he wouldn't.  Or that you're wrong.  But it does seem like you are putting words in his mouth by claiming he said it in this article.  Re. Armageddon + Second Coming, it is a claim oft made, but I haven't seen it backed up by actual citations.  Is there more substance to be cited, by actual Iranian leaders saying it here?  There could be, after all the deleted answer below just straight out quotes the Quran in what could be interpreted as saying something similar.
